# Why is the last tab- pane always active even after selecting other tabs?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am working with bootstrap on this large view containing sub views. I have a ton of tabs on the larger view but only one set of them malfunctions consistently. I have checked the syntax against that of the other working tab pills sections but the last tab section is always present.

```
<div class="row" style="height:350px">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <h3>Users</h3>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

                            <li id="Cre" class ="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#CreUser" onchange="HideIt(1)"> Create User</a></li>
                            <li id="Mod"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#ModUser" onchange="HideIt(2)"> Modify User</a></li>
                            <li id="Del"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#DelUser" onchange="HideIt(3)"> Delete User</a></li>
                        </ul>


                    </div>
                    <div class="container col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-1" style="height:95%;border-radius:70px;border-color:darkblue; border:1px solid">
                        <div class="tab-content col-lg-offset-1">
                            <div id="CreUser" class="tab-pane active">
                                @Html.Action("CreateUser", "Home")
                            </div>
                            <div id="ModUser" class="tab-pane">
                                @Html.Action("ModifyUser", "Home")
                            </div>
                          //  NO MATTER WHAT THIS TAB ALWAYS APPEARS IN THE PANE OR IS PUSHED DOWN OUT OF THE WINDOW PANE BY THE OTHER TAB SECTIONS
                            <div id="DelUser" class="tab-pane">
                                @Html.Action("DeleteUser", "Home")
                            </div>
                           

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[Example Screenshot of Tab Malfuction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6opn.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed an extra `div` element that was within my Modify user action view. which was causing my tab-pane to exit early which cause the next tab-pane to always be active.

Answer (score 0):

Link the Bootstrap in order :

- bootstrap.css
- jquery.min
- bootstrap.js

`Check out this:`     [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koesr2us/)

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone use this in the future, in my specific case, I had more than one group of tabs that were used for different purposes. And the ***href*** of tabs was the same. So I used different values for the tab hrefs and the tab pane ***Id***s and it was resolved :)